# How am I doing with carry and overflow with this code?

Tags: c++, if-statement, integer-overflow

I just have some issues with carry and overflow with this code I've been assigned to create. The assessor has asked me to deduct values from a double (which I don't know is the right function). Also, do I need secD and minD?

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main (){


    double degA;
    double degB;
    double degC;
    double minA;
    double minB;
    double minC;
    double minD;
    double secA;
    double secB;
    double secC;
    double secD;
    double carryM;
    double carryS;

    cout << "input all values for degree number one in this order: Degree°Minute'Second. Repeat this process when I say so.";
    cin >> degA;
    cin >> minA;
    cin >> secA;

    cout << "do it again";
    cin >> degB;
    cin >> minB;
    cin >> secB;

    secD = secA + secB;

    if (secD >= 60){
        secC = secD - 60;
        carryS = 1;
    }
    else {
        secC = secD;
        carryS = 0;
    }
    minD = minA + minB + carryS;

    if (minD >= 60){
        minC = minD - 60;
        carryM = 1;
    }
    else {
        minC = minD;
        carryM = 0;
    }
    degC = degA + degB + carryM;
    cout << degC << "°" << minC << "'" << secC;





}
```

Comment: What is your problem? The code seems to be a little bit too complicated for the task, but it looks okay. It also seems to work: https://ideone.com/TwHRar Does your prof want you to transform the degree+min+sec values to a `double`, add them and transform them back to degree+min+sec?

Comment: @mch the instructions had this algorithm:

"request the first angle, storing the input in degA, minA and secA

request the second angle, storing the input in degB, minB and secB

add secA and secB producing secC

IF secC > 60

deduct 60 from secC

set carry to 1

ELSE

carry is 0

add minA and minB and carry producing minC

IF minC > 60

deduct 60 from minC

set carry to 1

ELSE

carry is 0

add degA and degB and carry producing degC

report the results, including echoing the inputs"

Comment: Is this the description of the task from your prof? Then your code is fine.